# How to dim the status bar in a fragment

Tags: android

Im trying to dim the status bar at the bottom of the screen in a fragment, then show it again when the fragment goes away.  Here's the code:

```
@Override
public void onPause()
{
    super.onPause();
    getActivity().getActionBar().show();
    getView().setSystemUiVisibility(View.STATUS_BAR_VISIBLE);
}

@Override
public void onStart()
{
    super.onStart();
    getActivity().getActionBar().hide();
    getView().setSystemUiVisibility(View.STATUS_BAR_HIDDEN);
}
```

If the user launches my fragment, it works.  It dims correctly.  But if they hit "back", it seems like the status bar gets shown again correctly, but then after a split second, it goes dim again by itself.  Has any one else seen this behavior?  I think the system is doing something automatically with the status bar, but I cant figure out what it is.  If I take out my call to show the status bar, it still shows it by itseft if the user hits back, but then a split second later, it gets dimmed again.

Comment: Can't repeat your problem. Also, you don't need to hide/unhide in onStart/onPause, it's enough to hide in onCreate, Android will know when your app is inactive and manage hiding/dimming itself.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same issue. I think the problem was that I wasn't setting the visibility on the main content view. I ended up copying the code from HoneycombGallery's ContentFragment.java and that finally worked for me.